# phantomjs/casperjs force page caching

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

I am trying to force phantoms to in-memory cache some webpage (GET) that is sending "Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate” header to us.

I ve tried to do this by modifying Cache-Control header in casper.options.onResourceReceived  but it seems the headers are kind of a READ-ONLY in this callback?!

I would appreciate some directions to investigate in this problem …..

Answer (score 0):

If the server doesn't want a request cached, then there is nothing you can do. PhantomJS is just another browser, so it will follow those instructions.